# How to put groupby result into the same row

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id' :["c1","c1","c1","c2","c2","c3","c3","c3","c3","c4","c4","c5","c6","c6","c6","c7","c7"],'store'  : ["first","second","second","first",
                                "second","first","third","fourth",
                                "fifth","second","fifth","first",
                                "first","second","third","fourth","fifth"],
                      'purchase': [10,10,10,20,20,30,30,30,30,40,40,50,60,60,60,70,70]})
```

after you do groupby:

```
df_group= df.groupby(['id','store']).agg({'purchase': ["sum"]})
```

[Result of df_group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpO2Y.png)

I want to let each card have all the purchases in the different stores appear in the same row, for example:

```
  id 1_store 1_sum 2_store 2_sum 3_store 3_sum 4_store 4_sum...
0 c1 first   10    second  20
1 C2 first   20    second  20
2 c3 fifth   30    first   30    fourth  30    third   30
```

I don't want to use unstack on store, the reason behind it is there are so many stores, it will cause too much columns for stores and most of them are empty.

How can I achieve the above result?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to create a `cumcount` variable to get the column labels, then this becomes a `.pivot_table` problem: You get quite the `MultiIndex` on the columns, which we can collapse:

```
df_group['idx'] = df_group.groupby(level=0).cumcount()+1

df_res = (df_group.reset_index()
              .pivot_table(index='id', 
                           columns='idx', 
                           values=['store', 'purchase'], 
                           aggfunc='first')
              .sort_index(level=2, axis=1))
```

#### Output:

```
    purchase  store purchase   store purchase   store purchase  store
         sum             sum              sum              sum       
idx        1      1        2       2        3       3        4      4
id                                                                   
c1      10.0  first     20.0  second      NaN     NaN      NaN    NaN
c2      20.0  first     20.0  second      NaN     NaN      NaN    NaN
c3      30.0  fifth     30.0   first     30.0  fourth     30.0  third
c4      40.0  fifth     40.0  second      NaN     NaN      NaN    NaN
c5      50.0  first      NaN     NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN    NaN
c6      60.0  first     60.0  second     60.0   third      NaN    NaN
c7      70.0  fifth     70.0  fourth      NaN     NaN      NaN    NaN
```

If need to collapse the columns (probably a good idea since it's not lexsorted anymore):

```
df_res.columns = ['_'.join(map(str, [y for y in x[::-1] if y != ''])) for x in df_res.columns]

    1_sum_purchase 1_store  2_sum_purchase 2_store  3_sum_purchase 3_store  4_sum_purchase 4_store
id                                                                                                
c1            10.0   first            20.0  second             NaN     NaN             NaN     NaN
c2            20.0   first            20.0  second             NaN     NaN             NaN     NaN
c3            30.0   fifth            30.0   first            30.0  fourth            30.0   third
c4            40.0   fifth            40.0  second             NaN     NaN             NaN     NaN
c5            50.0   first             NaN     NaN             NaN     NaN             NaN     NaN
c6            60.0   first            60.0  second            60.0   third             NaN     NaN
c7            70.0   fifth            70.0  fourth             NaN     NaN             NaN     NaN
```